# How to define 2 routes to seperate 2 categories of 1 object in Ruby on Rails 5.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My application manages Business Objects. I have 2 categories of Business Objects:

1. The "template" Business Objects
2. The "implemented" Business Objects

They are identical, but the "implemented" category members always refer to a "template", and have some fields that appear as read-only in the edit view. So I have only 1 class, and 1 controller. A "is_template" flag marks template Business Objects.

Now a new requirement requests these 2 categories to be separated at routing level. On one route, only "template" Business Objects can be managed, on the other route, "implemented" Business Objects can be managed. Both through the same controller. I tried the following, but don't know how to handle it:

```
  resources :business_objects, :path => "template_metadata" do
    resources :skills       # Attributes of a business object
    member do
      post :new_version     # Manage some flags for templates
      post :make_current
      post :finalise
    end
    collection do
      get :index_used      # Former way to list only implemented business objects
    end
  end

  resources :implemented_objects, controller: 'business_objects' do
    resources :skills       # Attributes of a business object
  end
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of problem you faced? Because now I think it is not enough to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to add an extra parameter into your routes so that you can check which type of object it is in your controller. If you wrap your routes in a scope with a named parameter, it can pass that through to your controller.
For example,

```
scope ":type", constraints: { :type => /(template|implemented)/ } do
  resources :business_objects, :path => "template_metadata" do
    resources :skills       # Attributes of a business object
    member do
      post :new_version     # Manage some flags for templates
      post :make_current
      post :finalise
    end
    collection do
      get :index_used      # Former way to list only implemented business objects
    end
  end

  resources :implemented_objects, controller: 'business_objects' do
    resources :skills       # Attributes of a business object
  end
end
```

will force all of these routes to be prefixed with a `type` and you will be able to access `params[:type]` in your controller. The `constraints: { :type => /(template|implemented)/ }` part ensures that the only types are `template` or `implemented`.